# Roots of equation involving both polynomials and trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, roots

I have to determine for which values of $x$ that the velocity vector is orthogonal to the acceleration vector, the position is given by:

$(3 \cos(t), - \sin(3t), 2t^3 - t^2)$,

I then use that $u \cdot v = 0$ if $u$ and $v$ is orthogonal. The dot product of the acceleration and velocity gives the following equation (if I have done the differentiation correctly):

$9\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)-27\cos\left(3t\right)\sin\left(3t\right)+4t\left(18t^2-9t+1\right) = 0$.

$t = 0$ (or position $x = (3,0,0)$) is clearly a root but i can't find the other two. Is there a general way of computing roots of this sort of function analytically?

Comment: Except in very special cases, equations involving both trig functions and polynomials cannot be solved explicitly in the sense you probably intend. Are you SURE this is not a calculator exercise, [where you solve by the use of a graphing calculator](https://www.dummies.com/education/graphing-calculators/ti-84-plus-calculators-equation-solver/)?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I had a small typo in the equation, it is corrected now. But yes, this was given to students as a question in multivariate calculus on a test.

Comment: @Blue You are correct, thanks.

Comment: *But yes, this was given to students as a question in multivariate calculus on a test.* --- Were calculators allowed to be used on the test?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro No, only pencil and eraser.

Comment: Using the identity $\sin u \cos u = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2u$ for $u=t$ and $u=3t,$ the trig expressions combine to $\frac{9}{2}\sin 2t - \frac{27}{2}\sin 6t.$ Each of $\frac{9}{2}\sin 2t$ and $-\frac{27}{2}\sin 6t$ is relatively straightforward to graph, so you can graph the tig part by [this method](http://www.mathskey.com/question2answer/26550/use-the-method-of-adding-y-coordinates-to-graph-the-function). You can also graph the cubic relatively easily. Graphing both the trig part and the cubic together shows there are three solutions and roughly where they are located.

Comment: I haven't checked your differentiation and dot product results, but it doesn't appear that the equation you have given has explicit solutions besides $x=0.$ Moreover, even if by chance there is some trig identity process I've overlooked, all that would do is demonstrate (to me, at least) that the problem is not useful for its intended purpose, but rather it was artificially rigged to be solvable by hand *without appearing to be solvable by hand* (something that serves almost no useful purpose in aiding one's understanding of multivariable calculus).

Comment: @Loggoman your computation is correct. Wolframalpha gives as solutions $0$ and two approximate values (quoting): "near to -0.348615" and "near to 0.462221", input: solve  9cos(x)*sin(x)-27cos(3x)*sin(3x)+(12x-2)*(6x-2)*x=0